# How can I make a $function echo <div> PHP

Tags: php, html

Hey I have a question that I can not seem to figure out, how can I make a $function echo a html markup like this code:

```
<div style="color: purple;">Hello</div>
```

I can not seem to get it. Here is the code I am using is not working:

```
$contactUs = echo <div style="color: green;">click here</div>;
```

How can I make my $function work?

Comment: Have you searched for it at least? http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/tut.php

Comment: `$function` ?... what `$function`? or do my eyes deceive me? Never mind [I found it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19692291/1415724)

Comment: [Do read up on what a **function( )** is](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$contactUs = '<div style="color: green;">click here</div>';
echo $contactUs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you're asking about, but you can do:

```
$function = function() { echo '<div style="color: green;">click here</div>'; };
...
$function();
```

Comment: This is what I first thought, but I just read the question again and arrived at the conclusion that OP doesn't know the basics of PHP. Close-voted.

Comment: good answer, but I doubt the OP will understand anonymous functions :(

Answer (score 0):

1° In php, all strings need to be surrounded by quotes:

```
'<div style="color: green;">click here</div>';
```

Then, `echo` is a language construct which send text to output (your screen for example);

```
// If you want to use a variable
$contactUs = '<div style="color: green;">click here</div>';
echo $contactUs;

// but you can use echo 'your string':
echo '<div style="color: green;">click here</div>';
```